# scala Future to run sequential jobs

Tags: scala, future

I'm trying to launch three jobs sequentially, but when I try this code :

```
val jobs = Seq("stream.Job1","stream.Job2","stream.Job3")
    Future.sequence {
          jobs.map { jobClass =>
            Future {
              println(s"Starting the spark job from class $jobClass...")
              % gcloud("sparkC", "jobs", "submit", "spark", s"--cluster=$clusterName", s"--class=$jobClass", "--region=global", s"--jars=$JarFile")
              println(s"Starting the spark job from class $jobClass...DONE")
            }
          }
        }
```

I get the three jobs in parallel, then sequential.
I think the solution is to work with `flatMap` But I'm not able to implement it.
Any help please.

Comment: What do you mean by "in parallel, then sequential"? Do the jobs stop dead in their tracks when halfway done, and then line themselves up in a sequential queue of some sort?

Comment: Are you trying to run a job which depends on the output three jobs (running parallely)?

Comment: If you want sequential execution, why are you even using Future?

Comment: I want run job by job (one after the other). when job1 ends job2 start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
val jobs = Seq("stream.Job1","stream.Job2","stream.Job3")
jobs.foldLeft(Future.successful[Unit]()) {
  case (result, jobClass) =>
    result.flatMap[Unit] {_ =>
      Future {
        println(s"Starting the spark job from class $jobClass...")
        % gcloud("sparkC", "jobs", "submit", "spark", s"--cluster=$clusterName", s"--class=$jobClass", "--region=global", s"--jars=$JarFile")
        println(s"Starting the spark job from class $jobClass...DONE")
      }
    }.
      recoverWith {
      case NonFatal(e) => result
    }
}
```

This will iterate over your jobs and run next future as soon as previous was completed. I added `recoverWith` block to process all `Futures` independently if any of them failed

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you edit your code with my example ?

Answer (score 1):

If the jobs do not depend on each other, and if you want to have a list of results 
in the end, you can use this:

```
import scala.concurrent._
def runIndependentSequentially[X]
  (futs: List[() => Future[X]])
  (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[List[X]] = futs match {
  case Nil => Future { Nil }
  case h :: t => for {
    x <- h()
    xs <- runIndependentSequentially(t)
  } yield x :: xs
}
```

Now you can use it on your list of futures of jobs as follows:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

val jobs = List("stream.Job1","stream.Job2","stream.Job3")
val futFactories = jobs.map { jobClass =>
  () => Future {
    println(s"Starting the spark job from class $jobClass...")
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    "result[" + jobClass + "," + (System.currentTimeMillis / 1000) % 3600 + "]"
  }
}

println(Await.result(runIndependentSequentially(futFactories), 30 seconds))
```

This produces the following output:

```
Starting the spark job from class stream.Job1...
Starting the spark job from class stream.Job2...
Starting the spark job from class stream.Job3...
List(result[stream.Job1,3011], result[stream.Job2,3016], result[stream.Job3,3021])
```

**UPDATE**: replaced list of futures by `List[() => Future[X]]`, so that the 
evaluation of the futures does not start even before the argument is passed to the
`runIndependentSequentially` method. Greats thanks @Evgeny for pointing it out!

Comment: I'm afraid this will not work. Add, for example, timestamp in output and you will see that all futures will be started as soon as they are mapped, not sequentially.

Comment: @Evgeny Thanks, fixed!